# Self executing function as object property value in javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to have a self executing function which is an objects property value assign values to other properties in the object?

e.g. - what I would like to do is this:

```
var b={
  c:'hi',
  d:null,
  e:new function(){this.d=5}
};
```

But the "this" inside the new function seems to refer to b.e. Is it possible to access the b.e parent (i.e. b) from inside the function?

Comment: I can't see why you'd want to instantiate an anonymous function as you currently are.

Comment: What is your end goal here? To execute code during the object's creation that edits other properties of the object?

Comment: @jackwanders - yep. I was just wondering if it was possible to do it this way as a sort of shortcut to jakeclarckson's method below.

Comment: Work with functions! They are first-class objects in javascript, so they are very powerful. Never use the `new` operator! (Except for selfmade objects) Also you should read something about scope and closures in Javascript.

Comment: @Christoph I tried it using `(function(){}())` but "this" inside the function referred to the Window object rather than `b` using the `new` operator seemed to be the only way to get access to `b` inside the function.

Answer (score 7):

This is how you do it.

Often called the module pattern ([more info](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-module-pattern))

```
var b = function () {
   var c = 'hi';
   var d = null;

   return {
     c : c,
     d : d,
     e : function () {
       // this function can access the var d in the closure.
       d = 5;
     }
   }
}();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the value within the `function`, you just need to get rid of the `new`, i.e.

```
e: function () {
    this.d = 5;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but that wont assign the value to b.d unless I call b.e(). I was hoping to use a self executing function to do it.

Comment: But then you have to explicitely call b.e() - this binds e to the the object b. Which is not the case with a selfexecuting function.